# Unable to Grant session to a user

Tags: oracle, session, sqlplus

I used yesterday the sqlplus on ubuntu 14.04LTS normally but today when I open it I connect to the System :

```
SQL> connect system
Enter Password : 
Connected.
```

Then I want to connect to my account which I created yesterday :

```
SQL> connect slim/slimhmidi;
Connected.
```

when I want to create as session I had this error:

```
SQL> grant session to slim;
grant session to slim
      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01919: role ' SESSION ' does not exist
```

I tried to create a session but no vain:

```
SQL> grant create session to slim;
grant create session to slim
*
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Also I have this error :

```
SQL> grant connect to slim;
grant connect to slim
      *
```

ERROR at line 1:
   ORA-01932: admin option not granted for role ' CONNECT'
However I didn't have these problems yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORA-01919: role ' SESSION ' does not exist

You are trying to grant the privilege to user `slim` while you are already connected to `slim`. So, the grantor and grantee are same here.

> ORA-01932: admin option not granted for role ' CONNECT

As I said, you are already connected as user `slim`, it means the user already has the **CONNECT** privilege.

To grant create session to the user, you could do it as **SYS** user or any other user which has the **privilege to grant**.

See this link to documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#DBSEG10000

**Update** Per OP's comments

To give the select privilege on the table to a user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table_name TO slim;
```

Comment: when I write to select the columns of one of the tables I wrote I have this error :ORA- 00942 : table or view does not exist.

Comment: Then you need to grant select to that user.

Comment: ORA- 01919 : the role 'SELECT' does not exist

Comment: I understand the mistake I have made,I connect to slim then I want to grant to create session and connect to slim which is false.I connect to system then I grant connect to slim and create session,it works.I have only one problem I want to select the column of my table what can I do??I connect to slim then I do select * from table,when I did this command I Had this problem"ORA- 00942 : table or view does not exist"

Comment: Connect to system, and do `GRANT SELECT ON table_name TO slim;` Please mark it as answered.